# Bootstrap5 ссылка внутри аккордеона

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, bootstrap

Имеется блок-аккордеон, в шапке `.accordion-header` имеется кнопка, по которой раскрывается список, но при этом сама кнопка содержит ссылку. При попытке нажать на ссылку срабатывает действие по раскрытию списка(т.е. срабатывает кнопка), хотя браузер подсвечивает ссылку. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку был переход по ссылку, а при нажатии на кнопку(которая эту ссылку содержит) срабатывало раскрытие?

```
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="ThemesList">
                {% for t in themes%}
                  <div class="accordion-item rounded border border-dark mt-1">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="{{t.title_url}}">
                            <button class="accordion-button {%if t.title_url == theme.title_url%}{%else%}collapsed{%endif%}" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-{{t.title_url}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-{{t.title_url}}" role="button">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{%url 'tutorial:theory' t.title_url%}">
                                    {{t.title}}
                                </a>
                            </button>
                 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: У Вас невалидная разметка - кнопка не может содержать в себе ссылку. "Error: The element a must not appear as a descendant of the button element" - такую ошибку фиксирует валидатор w3c. Меняйте разметку.

Answer (score 0):

Держать ссылку внутри button, решение неправильное.
Есть множество других способов.

Например, можете оставить чисто ссылку на другую страницу, но поверх нее наложить невидимый слой открывающий аккордеон, который будет пропадать после раскрытия и последующие клики уже будут приходиться непосредственно на ссылку.

Либо, можете внутри ссылки сделать иконку стрелку, при клике по которой будет открываться аккордеон.

Либо оставить ссылку, клик по которой открывает аккордеон, а после открытия, с помощью JS полностью заменить эту ссылку на другую, которая уже будет вести на нужную страницу.

Либо ...
Либо ...

Comment: Спасибо большое!